# django admin breadcrumbs based on history

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to override breadcrumbs in Django admin. I want to have history breadcrumbs. Anyone to know if someone already wrote something similar?

Comment: Isn't that functionality built into the web browser? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, but i want to display it under the Header ... like now but instead harcode django breadcrumb (Home>APP name>ChangeLISTName>ChangeFormName) i want historical display.

Comment: Are you just asking for a tool/library recommendation? What have you tried?